# MySQL - update specific (NOT CURRENT) date - substract by 1 year

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I update the field `bday` and set it one year back? I have found thousands of answer where it shows how substract from current damn time but how to do it with one which is already set?

This is what I've tried:

```
UPDATE user SET `bday` = DATE_ADD(`bday`, INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
```

It just ignores the `-` and set it one year forward

**EDIT:**

I use mysql with PHP

This is what I also tried:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `bday` = DATE_SUB(`bday`, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Comment: The update seems correct. Are you sure it updates one year forward?

Comment: yeah absolutely sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Sql server

```
UPDATE user SET bday = DATEADD(Year, -1, bday)
```

MySql

UPDATE user SET `bday` = DATE_SUB(`bday`, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

Comment: This is what I also tried but I get #1305 error (Function does not Exist)

Comment: This answer for sql-server. I think King Dingeling use mysql.

Comment: The field type is DATE and the values like: 1969-03-18

Comment: I tried with "SELECT DATE_SUB("1969-03-18", INTERVAL 1 YEAR);  ", the result is correct "1968-03-18", try update directly like UPDATE user SET bday= ''1968-03-18", what's the result ?

Comment: Oh damn I looked at the "age" which is calculated the whole time, this is what happens after 12 hours coding, this is embarrassing xD thanks!